# peakDetect does not seem to work as expected

Tags: javascript, p5.js, p5.sound.js

I've added to my script from [an example on the p5.js website](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.PeakDetect).

I'd expect that an amplitude beyond 1.0 would satisfy the condition of their being a peak. I have set my amplitude range from 0 to 1.2, depending on the mouse y position. I can see that the amplitude reads out as 1.2, but the `peakDectect.isDetected` does not trigger.

`fft.analyze` was called, then fft is passed to `peakDetect.update()` so that it reads `peakDetect.update(fft)`.

Code I'm using is below.

```js
let fft, peakDetect, osc, lfo, playing, freq, amp;

function setup() {
  let cnv = createCanvas(300, 100);
  cnv.mousePressed(playOscillator);
  osc = new p5.Oscillator('sine');
  lfo = new p5.Oscillator('sine');
  filter = new p5.Filter();
  fft = new p5.FFT();
  peakDetect = new p5.PeakDetect();

  // chain
  lfo.disconnect();
  osc.disconnect();
  osc.connect(filter);
}

function draw() {
  background(220)
  freq = constrain(map(mouseX, 0, width, 40, 1000), 40, 1000);
  amp = constrain(map(mouseY, height, 0, 0, 1.2), 0, 1.2);

  if (playing) {
    // smooth the transitions by 0.1 seconds
    lfo.freq(2.9);
    osc.freq(freq, 0.1);
    osc.amp(amp, 0.1);
    filter.freq(1200);

    filter.res(14);
    // how many Hz should the LFO oscillate
    lfo.amp(1500);

    // connect the lfo
    filter.freq(lfo);

    let spectrum = fft.analyze();

    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 255);
    for (let i = 0; i < spectrum.length; i++) {
      let x = map(i, 0, spectrum.length, 0, width);
      let h = -height + map(spectrum[i], 0, 255, height, 0);
      rect(x, height, width / spectrum.length, h)
    }

    let waveform = fft.waveform();
    noFill();
    beginShape();
    stroke(255, 100, 0);
    for (let i = 0; i < waveform.length; i++) {
      let x = map(i, 0, waveform.length, 0, width);
      let y = map(waveform[i], -1, 1, 0, height);
      vertex(x, y);
    }
    endShape();

    // fft.analyze() has already been called.
    // check fft for peak detection. 
    peakDetect.update(fft);

    var ellipseWidth = 10;

    if (peakDetect.isDetected) {
      ellipseWidth = 50;
    } else {
      ellipseWidth *= 0.95;
    }

    noStroke();
    fill(0, 0, 0);

    ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, ellipseWidth, ellipseWidth);
  }

  fill(0, 0, 0);
  noStroke();
  text('tap to play', 20, 20);
  text('freq: ' + freq, 20, 40);
  text('amp: ' + amp, 20, 60);
}

function playOscillator() {
  osc.start();
  lfo.start();
  playing = true;
}

function mouseReleased() {
  // ramp amplitude to 0 over 0.5 seconds
  osc.amp(0, 0.2);
  playing = false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 I don't understand the reasoning behind adding the "Run code snippet" button, since it won't be able to run without p5.js and p5.sound.js. Could you enlighten me? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't add any button. This was somebody else. Check out the edit history and don't blame me! I just removed [tag:p5.js] from the title because there is no point in adding tags to the title of the question.

Comment: Got it! I did not notice anyone else doing edits. I'll go back and check. Sorry about that. @ggorlen ??

Comment: Yep, I converted it to a runnable snippet, which I do with just about all p5.js examples. I forgot the sound library, but it's added now. In the future, I recommend making it a snippet on your own. It makes it a lot easier to see the problem without having to copy paste the code elsewhere and figure out all of the imports, etc. Also, sometimes problems are due to specific versions of libraries, so please take a moment to make sure your issue is reproducible on 1.4.1.

Comment: Thanks @ggorlen ; I did not know you could add libraries like that. For me, the snippet is stuck on "loading", even after emptying caches. This might be because there is no html?

Comment: It works on FF and Chrome for me. p5.js doesn't need HTML and the snippet adds the basic body tag.

Comment: I see. I guess Safari is to blame, or maybe lacking support. It works on Chrome for me too, but the peakDetect issue is still there.

Comment: I could get peakDetect to fire if I set the threshold to 0.02 or less: myPeakDetect = new p5.PeakDetect(20,20000,0.02,20); but it's not a regular beat like it is when you use the song 'beat.mp3'.  Used Chrome browser.